# Elixir/Phoenix - what are the variables that are prefixed with @ (eg - @type or @impl)

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm following some tutorials but got confused seeing these variables, what exactly are these and what are they called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are [module attributes](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/module-attributes.html).

There are some *predefined* module attributes, as described in [`Module`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html?#module-module-attributes) documentation. `@impl` and `@type` are the predefined ones, described in the documentation for [`Module`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Module.html?#module-module-attributes) I referenced above.

It’s always a good idea to start with the language core and only then dive into frameworks, but since your question also mentioned [phoenix-framework](/questions/tagged/phoenix-framework), it’s worth to mention that *Phoenix* nicely plays with module hooks, implicitly declaring some module attributes for convenient access to `@assigns` and like, but this is surely out of the scope of your current journey.